# How to use two factor authorization cookie along with single factor authorization cookie

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

I have a web application with singe factor authorization and now have implemented two-factor authorization. I am using the [Microsoft Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) for the log-in. The problem is - so far we have used a cookie to remember the user while providing the username and password. Say that as 'signglefactorcookie'. Now on the authenticator application authorization page(TFA), I have added another cookie for the remember me option. Say that as 'twofactorcookie'. Now how can I make my client request for both cookies when I use the below code?

```
// Check whether there is a valid session or persistent cookie

if(this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
// Move to a landing page
}
```

**Problem scenario**

1. Now the problem is, if I log in to the single-factor authentication page with the correct user name and password and land at the two-factor authentication page.
2. Open a new tab and try to access the home page getting success since there is a single factor cookie that is recognized which makes the user authorized.

How can I make it in a standard way?

Comment: Not clear why are you mixed them togerther. By the way which version of `asp.net core` are you using? I would highly recommend you to check the [`official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/2fa?view=aspnetcore-1.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-6.0) for standard implementation practice.

Comment: Thanks, @MdFaridUddinKiron. I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1. I will look into the shared link.

Comment: Did you had the chance to check the official document, have you made any progress?